# Delphi: Array of TVarRec vs. varArray

Tags: arrays, delphi, variadic-functions

I want to use an open array with a variety of types (ex: `['string',12,123.21]`). During my search, I've found two ways to do that. One is with `array of TVarRec` and the other is using `varArray`. I'm thinking that the array of *TVarRec* is the best choice, because it appears to be more lightweight, on the other hand the *varArray* already have some implementations that I'll have to create if I want to use arrays of *TVarRec*.

Does someone have any opinions about the usage of these two ways?

Comment: Open array of TVarRec is actually `array of const`, you can use the same way as in `Format` function.

Comment: @Serg, make your comment an answer, it's the correct answer IMHO

Comment: @ldsandon - OK, I posted a comment because the question is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could use an `array of Variant`?

Comment: I'll try this simple approach.

Comment: There are any disadvantage between array of variant and array of TVarRec?

Comment: I disagree, @David. The idiomatic Delphi way is `array of const`, like `SysUtils.Format` uses.

Comment: @Rob I'm sure you are right. I don't really like `TVarRec` though. It seems rather inconvenient to me.

Comment: @Rob, you're right if you're talking about parameters. But I think you cannot declare an array of const. Neither can you assign any value to a TVarRec. If you got a `var a: TVarRec`, you cannot write `a := 'whatever'` while that would be possible if `a` was a Variant.

Comment: @GolezTrol is possible assign a value to a parameter of type TVarRec, but its much more complicated. I'm already implement the Array of Variant way. Any issues i'll report. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for an open variant array, the solution is `array of const`.

`Array of const` is implemented internally as array of `TVarRec`. Read [Rudy Velthuis article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html) for details.

Comment: The question is whats the best choice, not "how can i implement this". But thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the best choice. Variants are heavyweight compared to this.